# Copying files from one folder to another using a shell script

Tags: shell

I have a script to copy the files from one location to another where i am passing the first location as parameter to the script

```
#!/bin/bash
locatn=$1
echo $locatn
cp -r  /locatn/ /ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/automation/
```

but when i run this code this throws error as
    **cp: cannot stat `locatn': No such file or directory**
what could be the issue

Comment: there is no directory you should check your folder

Comment: you are referring `locatn` in the root directory, use this to refer in the current directory like this: `cp -r  ./locatn/ /ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/automation/
`, note the dot which has been added

Comment: It should be `cp -r  ${locatn} /ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/automation/` no?

Comment: actually i am passing the location here as an argument to the script.the location variable has value /auto/ipcbu-build/Published/TPL_LIBRARIES/

Comment: @PatrickTrentin yes this worked..thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting looks a bit weird but as @Patick Trentin said you simply forgot a `$` making your script always copy the files to the same location ignoring the given parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash
locatn=$1
echo $locate

cp -r  /${locatn}/ /ws/priyapan-rcd/workspace/automation/
```